# SSIS Custom Log Provider - Reading Package Parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis, gac

I have implemented a custom SSIS log provider where the core SSIS log properties are conveyed to a web api endpoint to log to an external system by overriding the Log method. Where I am having difficulty is in understanding how to access the DTS Runtime Parameters to do different things based on the build mode.

In particular I have a Project Parameter in the SSIS project for "FilePath" (ex. "C:\debug.txt") that gets transformed based on the build to "C\release.txt" when in release mode.

I am unable to access the DTS runtime similar to script tasks in the custom log provider that is installed in the GAC so am looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't like that answer, however, it is not possible to access the package variables from the custom log provider similar to script tasks.

Referece: [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/df40680a-3a07-4dec-91d9-bc7c1aaa8c9b/reading-package-variables-from-custom-log-provider?forum=sqlintegrationservices)